# Using WCF 'Message' to call external service

Tags: wcf

I have a class, in which I have a service reference (WCF) to an ASMX web service.

This obviously generates local proxy methods such as

```
 string DoSomething(string someParameter, string someOtherParameter)
```

I have a method that receives a WCF message class already representing a call to this service, which I simply need to forward

I could of course use XmlDictionaryReader to extract the information from the WCF message, deserialise into the proxy classes and pass those into the proxy method, but as these will simply get serialised back it seems very wasteful

How can I call the service using the already serialised message? (I assume I will need to modify the soap action on the incoming message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a two-part series on how to build a [WCF router on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dvdarchive/cc500646.aspx) - maybe that helps? Seems like that's more or less what you're trying to do - use a WCF service to basically route a message on to a second service (ASMX in your case).

Marc